# How are chainlink requests processed when forking mainnet in Brownie?

Tags: chainlink

From the brownie chainlink-mix, why does the PriceFeed works fine on mainnet-fork while the ApiConsumer does not fulfill the request on the same network?
Are prices cached on the Aggregator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you fork the mainnet, it literally forks the blockchchain state at that point in time. So when you query the Price Feed Aggregator contract, you get the price at the time of forking.

However because there are no Chainlink oracles connected to your forked chain, there's no way to do a real API or VRF request...and the latest price data in Price Feed contracts won't update either.

Check out the tests to see how mocks are used for local environments where there is no connectivity to Chainlink nodes

Comment: Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: You can attempt to spin up a local chainlink node, and set the ETH_URL config to your local forked chain, so the node listens to your local chain for jobs, however this isn't officially supported yet as we see some inconsistent results. However some people have got it running https://docs.chain.link/docs/running-a-chainlink-node/. Once you get it running and talking with your local chain, you'd have to then attempt to setup and execute an API or VRF request

Comment: Super useful! Wouldn't setting up your own chainlink node and processing an API or VRF request actually cost gas though?